# В IE11 и Edge центрованное видео отображается некорректно, если установлен язык справа налево

Tags: css, видео, position, rtl

Чтобы центровать видео внутри родителя (с `position: relative;`), для тега `<video>` прописаны такие стили:

```
video {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Если для сайта установлен язык справа налево, то видео не видно.
Опытным путём установлено, что `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` сдвигает видео по горизонтали не влево, а вправо.
Причём, например, для `<img>`, `<span>` с такими же стилями всё отображается корректно.

Почему так происходит с `<video>`?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `direction:rtl;`

Comment: @KAGG Design, это есть.